# What is the proper way to represent an audio sample in two bytes?

Tags: arrays, file, audio, byte

I'm working on an application that generates a sequence of numbers representing a sine wave, and saves the sine wave in a `.wav` file to be played as audio.

The following line of code generates the value of a single sample in the audio wave:

```
double sample = Math.Sin(2.0 * Math.PI * frequency * i * (1.0 / samplesPerSecond));
```

The resulting `.wav` file will be of 16 bit depth. Meaning, each sample is represented by 2 bytes (`short`). `double` however takes up 8 bytes.

What is the proper way to encode a `sample` into the resulting `byte[]`, where it can only occupy 2 bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `sine` has a limited range `[-1.0, 1.0]`, you can map the value from that range to the range of 16-bit integers `[-32768, 32767]`.

```
short sample_short = SHORT_MAX * sample;
```

There will be some round-off error, but that's necessary to squeeze the values into the less precise data type.

The formula is only this simple because the range of `sine` is from `-1` to `1`. If you were working with some other value that has a different range, you need to normalize it first:

```
result = DST_TYPE_MAX * original / ORIGINAL_MAX;
```

This also assumes that the range of the original values is symmetric around `0`. If not, you need to do:

```
result = DST_TYPE_MAX * (original - ORIGINAL_MIN) / (ORIGINAL_MAX-ORIGINAL_MIN)
```

This only works for values that have a limited range. You can't do this kind of normalization for a function like `tangent`, since its range is infinite.

Comment: For audio purposes, if you were converting from float to int16 you would also want to apply dithering.  While it doesn't matter a whole lot for a simple sine wave, you will certainly notice a difference with more complicated sound.

Comment: It works! Thank you. Question: generally when dealing with situations like that, where I have to squeeze a value of a certain type into a certain number of bytes, is this the general approach to use? `dst_type result = DST_TYPE_MAX * original`? Or does it vary from case to case?

Comment: I've added generalizations to the answer.